# visual studio 2013 modify path variable when running .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, environment-variables

I have compiled an exe file in Visual Studio 2013, and it depends on some external files to function. I want to keep those files in the same folder that the exe is in. When I run the .exe by clicking on it in file explorer, it loads the files fine. However, when I run it from Visual Studio, it is unable to run because the PATH variable does not include the directory with the necessary files. How can I configure my project to run the program with a modified path variable so that it can access the files properly?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you question correctly. I suspect that this is an issue related to the different directories when you execute. In Visual Studio (to my knowledge), you have a folder named **Debug** and a second folder named **Release**.

You may choose in Visual Studio to run the program in either debug or release mode. But you might not have the required files neccessary in both directories.

**For example:**

I've made a program that reads "Hello World!" from **hello.txt**, and displays this in the dialog window as a string.

If I store the file in the **Release** directory, the executable will run fine outside the IDE, when just launching the executable file.

However, if you run the application in debug mode through the IDE (Visual Studio), the program will not find the neccessary file. The program is looking for the file in it's current directory (Debug).

A quick fix to this is to copy the required files to the current working directory. Eventually have a duplicate set of files in both directories at all times.

Hope that I did understand you correct, and that my answer helps you. :)

Comment: Sorry, that did not appear to work. I am only using the Debug project config for now, I have not even built with Release configs yet.

Comment: What kind of files are you refering to, dll files, text files etc?